# Returning character pointer and comparing with string

Tags: c, pointers

I am having one function which is returning character pointer
and it prototype is shown below.

```
char *substring(char *string, int position, int length);
```

calling function

```
char *temp1;
temp1 = substring(de1Binary, FieldNo - 1, 1);
```

return pointer if it is printed with %s it is showing temp1 = 1
After this the below code is executed

```
if (temp1 == "1")
{
     Inside loop
}
```

But it is not going inside loop.Here I think I am missing some basic concept in C program.
Please guide me.

Comment: use `strcmp` instead of `==`. E.g `if (strcmp(temp1, "1")  == 0)`

Comment: Or `strncmp` for non-case-sensitive string comparing

Comment: Thanks very silly mistake from my side.

Comment: You may want to [Answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Arc676: Err... [`strncmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) is not about case sensitivity, but for size limitation. If you intended that comment to be about `stricmp()`, *that* notable is not part of the language standard (i.e. not portable). And since it cannot even *know* the encoding you're working on, it's not to be recommended.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare the two strings use the strcmp() function it is in string.h header file.

Instead of if(temp1 == "1") you can use the below if statement.

```
if((strcmp(temp1, "1")) == 0)
{
     Inside loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you even write

```
if ("1" == "1")
```

there is no guarantee that this condition will yield `true`. It depends on the compiler options. It can store each of identical string literals separatly and in this case they will have different addresses or store only one string literal of identical literals.

String literals have type of character arrays. In the  if-condition string literals are converted implicitly to pointers to their first characters. So in this statement

```
if (temp1 == "1")
```

there is compared the address stored in temp1 with the address of the first character of string literal "1" that is stored in memory like

```
{ '1', '\0' }
```

So this condition will always yield `false` or either true or false (depending on the compiler options) if you write before the if statement

```
temp1 = "1";
```

You need to compare the strings pointed to by these two pointers not the pointers themselves. You could do this for example the following way

```
if ( temp1[0] == "1"[0] && temp1[1] == '\0' )  {*...*/ }
```

or

```
if ( temp1[0] == '1' && temp1[1] == '\0' )  {*...*/ }
```

Imagine for example that you have a manifest constant

```
#define One "1"
```

In this case you could write indeed

```
if ( temp1[0] == One[0] && temp1[1] == '\0' )  {*...*/ }
```

But it is much better to use standard C function `strcmp` declared in header `<string.h>` that returns 0 if two strings are equal.

```
if ( strcmp( temp1, "1" ) == 0 ) { /*...*/ }
```